# Is there a term to describe the physical location of an object, as well as the time in which it exists?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, time

Where such a term would reference the location/time of an object, almost like it was of a property of the object. That is to say, if a duck is red, blue, yellow etc, we describe it has having a certain colour. If it's a nanometre, or 10km big, then it's property of size.

Now I know that where/when an object exists an object isn't a property of an object, but it *is* something unique to that object, so I think it would be useful to have a shorthand for 'geographical location', and 'time of existence'.

There are terms describing both time and location, such an event, or rendezvous (which I think is used to describe the when and where of a meeting between two humans) but I wan't a term that just describes one of each.

Comment: An *event* is a perfectly good term. It is the preferred term for a "point" in spacetime.

Comment: "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered."  Please provide such a sentence or your question may be closed.

Comment: Annnd, how is that possible if the word/term to do so is lacking? You might as well close every question that asks for an appropriate word or term, if you're suggesting that one utilises the solution to their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location in space and time of an entity is its *spacetime coordinates*. (Sorry, I couldn't find a concise reference for this, but if you do a web search, you will get many hits.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain that I understand the question you are asking...but it sounds like you are describing adjectives, which express qualities of an object (physical or conceptual), such as blue, heavy, etc.

This same thing is done to reference physical location and time, which can be appended to nouns as "qualities" in the same way:

"The *6:30* *Soho* Train was late."

"The *midmorning* *downtown* traffic was horrendous."

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Trajectory.**

from wiki, which happens to provide a primary source. [trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory)

> A trajectory or flight path is the path that a moving object follows
>   through space as a function of time.[1]
>
> 1. The Principles of Physics by Rohit Metha, Chapter 11 Page 378 Para 3

Answer (score 0):

**Worldline**

This from wiki without a primary source. [worldline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line)

> In physics, the world line of an object is the path of that object in
>   4-dimensional spacetime, tracing the history of its location in space
>   at each instant in time.

Answer (score 0):

**Time-Geographic**

from wiki [time geography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_geography)

> Time geography is not only about time-geographic diagrams, just as
>   music is not only about musical notation.

scope of the idea

> Time geography or time-space geography is an evolving
>   transdisciplinary perspective on spatial and temporal processes and
>   events such as social interaction, ecological interaction, social and
>   environmental change, and biographies of individuals.[1] Time
>   geography "is not a subject area per se,"[2] but rather an integrative
>   ontological framework and visual language in which space and time are
>   basic dimensions of analysis of dynamic processes.

Answer (score 0):

A common adjective in [technical writing](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=spatiotemporal+&btnG=) is **spatio-temporal** or **spatiotemporal**. According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spatiotemporal):

> 1. of or existing in both space and time
> 2. of or concerned with space-time

Attribution: Definition of spatiotemporal from the Collins English Dictionary